# Moving from shared windows hosting to Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase

I am currently using Windows hosting for my Android app, from a local Domain provider.

I have developed and published my app on the Firebase platform. I want to know if moving (the hosting) from current Windows hosting to Firebase will make the app respond faster?

Answer (score 0):

firebase surely will respond faster as it use ssds as and seperated server cdn to reach user in global but it's just the server that cached and optimezed for faster respond it's depend to your code for threading the process for more tricky performance :)